# Uber API - Can we show local availability?

Tags: uber-api

We run real-time mobility and digital wayfinding signs (for digital totems etc) for the likes of TfL. A major airport has contacted us to ask if it is possible to show how many Ubers (by type) there are within the local vicinity. The idea is that we will provide an Uber logo and QR code for people to download the APP. Having tried to contact Uber directly we have not got any response and thought it may be a good idea to ask here. At this stage we just need to know if it's possible or not.

Thanks

Chris 
]